# Django how to filter based on ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Suppose I have the following Django classes:

in myclassa.py:

```
class MyClassA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)

    def my_method(self):
        # WHAT GOES HERE?
```

in myclassb.py:

```
from myclassa import MyClassA
class MyClassB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    a = models.ManyToManyField(MyClassA, related_name="MyClassB_MyClassA")
```

Now suppose I have an instance `x` of `MyClassA`.
What do I put in `my_method()` such that it returns all the instances of `MyClassB` that contain `x` in their field `a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may define it as:

```
def my_method(self):
    return self.MyClassB_MyClassA.all()
```

Alternatively, you may also define it as:

```
def my_method(self):
    return MyClassB.objects.filter(a=self)
```

Comment: Thanks. The first one will work. The second one won't because `MyClassB` is not imported into `myclassa.py`

Comment: Use whatever suits your requirement. In fact, 1st one is the preferred way to achieve it.